# Using web.config from base folder and not bin folder

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have an asp.net mvc web page.  I'm using config transforms with it.  The config transform in the bin directory is correct.  However, when I debug with IIS express, all the app settings being used are actually from the original web.config, not the transformed web.config in the bin folder.  If I rename the web.config to something else in the root folder, debugging will halt as soon as it tries to read a connection string because it says it's not initialized.  What is the problem?

Comment: Please share a sample of your web.configand the transformation

Answer (score 1):

Transformations only apply when you publish the project. However their is a hack to it

You can try using the below code. Your original configuration should be in Web.Base.Config

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml 
        Source="Web.Base.config" 
        Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" 
        Destination="Web.config" />
</Target>
```

You can also refer to below URL as sometime it makes transformation twice and you need to add steps for beforebuild

https://sebnilsson.com/blog/asp-net-transform-web-config-with-debug-release-on-build/

Comment: As I said, my transformation is occurring correctly.  The transformed file is being produced in the bin directory even without publishing.

I tried your sugestion.  However, VS said "debugging cannot continue because debugging is not enabled.  Would you like to add a web config and enable debugging?".  VS then added a web.config.  When run, the app quickly failed because one of my connection strings had not "been initialized".  This is no doubt because the web.config VS made is empty.  The web.config in the bin directory is correct but it's still using the web.config in the root directory.